# Sublime Text throwing "Permission Denied" when running glslViewer

Tags: sublimetext2

I have installed the glslViewer plugin for Sublime Text 2, which is supposed to run when I open a .frag file. When I open a file the following error appears:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
[cmd:  [u'/Users/austin/glslViewer', u'red.frag']]
[dir:  /Users/austin/procgraphics/Project1-Noise/src/shaders]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

I changed the permissions to read & write for the folders in path, but the error still occurs. What's going on?

Comment: Can you run `/Users/austin/glslViewer` from a terminal interactively? `EACCESS` (errno 13) can be thrown not only if there are permission problems accessing the folder but also if the thing you're trying to run is not executable

Answer (score 1):

Solved it: the path in glslViewer.sublime-settings was pointing to `/Users/austin/glslViewer/` instead of `/Users/austin/glslViewer/bin/` which is where the executable is located.